# Prompt File Search in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, file, search, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse that collects some data from the project that's currently opened and from current selection and I want to let the user open the File Search window that comes with Eclipse by double-clicking some of the data shown.

Ideally "Containing text" will be set to the data the user double-clicked, "Regular expression" unchecked, "File name patterns" set to "*.*" and "Scope" set to "Workspace"

Is there a way to show the Eclipse File Search dialog from my code?

Comment: I found that I can run the File Search dialog by executing its command:

ICommandService cmdService = (ICommandService) getSite().getService(ICommandService.class);
   handlerService = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);

   fileSearchCommand = cmdService.getCommand("org.eclipse.search.ui.openFileSearchPage");

 ...

ExecutionEvent exev = handlerService.createExecutionEvent(fileSearchCommand, new Event());
      fileSearchCommand.executeWithChecks(exev);

Comment: http://bassistance.de/2009/11/17/eclipse-dev-custom-search-page/

boils down to:
NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred().createQuery(idText.getText()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at:

http://bassistance.de/2009/11/17/eclipse-dev-custom-search-page

boils down to:

```
NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred().createQu‌​ery(idText.getText()));
```